# Configuring global list of allowed classes for serialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, infinispan

I am using Inifinispan v12.1 with String Boot v2.5.2 via `org.infinispan:infinispan-spring-boot-starter-embedded`. In our application we are using custom classes which we would like to cache (very common case), however it turned out that starting from v10 these classes need to be listed in "allow list".

We are using `infinispan.xml` configuration passed via `infinispan.embedded.config-xml` property as advised by [sample project](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/blob/main/integrations/spring-boot/cache-embedded/src/main/resources/application.properties#L3).

**Question**: How is it possible to configure allow list globally for all caches by the means of XML configuration file?

I have considered the following options:

- System property `infinispan.deserialization.allowlist.regexps` (from [`ClassAllowList`](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/ad05d66f4e/commons/all/src/main/java/org/infinispan/commons/configuration/ClassAllowList.java#L48)) – not good choice as configuration will be spread between XML file and e.g. some other place. More over if the property is renamed in future Infinispan versions one would notice it only when application is run.
- Defining the `<cache-container><serialization><allow-list>` as to [documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/encoding/encoding.html#adding-deserialization-allowlist_marshaller-implementations) is not good option because will result several identical per-cache XML configuration blocks.

The corresponding Java Config for Spring Boot application would be:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class InfinispanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InfinispanGlobalConfigurationCustomizer globalCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.allowList().addRegexp("^org\\.mycompany\\.");
    }
}
```

P.S. Javadoc in [`GlobalConfiguration`](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/ad05d66f4e/core/src/main/java/org/infinispan/configuration/global/GlobalConfiguration.java#L32) assumes that there is `<default>` XML section the configuration can be read from, but in fact XML does not support it anymore.

P.P.S. Arguably the dots in the packages should be escaped in [`SpringEmbeddedModule`](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/ad05d66f4e/spring/spring5/spring5-embedded/src/main/java/org/infinispan/spring/embedded/SpringEmbeddedModule.java#L32) and start with `^` because [`ClassAllowList`](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/ad05d66f4e/commons/all/src/main/java/org/infinispan/commons/configuration/ClassAllowList.java#L146) uses `Matcher#find()` (`boolean regexMatch = compiled.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.matcher(className).find());`):

```
serializationAllowList.addRegexps("^java\\.util\\..*", "^org\\.springframework\\..*");
```